# Don't know why the two functions are showing undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

Why are the two functions in my react forms are showing undefined? How should i define them?

```
Line 10:5:  'formSubmit' is not defined  no-undef
```

```
const Form = () => {
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const [sent,setSent] = useState(false);

    formSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefaults();

        let data = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message
        }

    }
```

Comment: use `const formSubmit=`, you can not use such syntax inside function, only for class members "const" and "let" can be skipped

Answer (score 1):

You should only add `const` before your `formSubmit` callback function

```
const Form = () => {
    const [name,setName] = useState("");
    const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
    const [message,setMessage] = useState("");
    const [sent,setSent] = useState(false);

    const formSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefaults();

        let data = {
            name:name,
            email:email,
            message:message
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the keyword for declaring function

It should be

```
const formSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
        name:name,
        email:email,
        message:message
    }

}
```

OR

```
function formSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message,
    };
  }
```

Also **preventDefaults** is wrong, **preventDefault** is correct.